# Получить размер файла подкачки через WinAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, swap

Подскажите. Как можно получить информацию о файле подкачке желательно через WinAPI? Пробывал через `GlobalMemoryStatusEx`, но данная функция выдаёт не правильные данные о файле подкачке.

Comment: А почему именно через WinApi? Есть более удобные решения через WMI или реестр. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441159/c-sharp-how-to-tell-if-system-has-virtual-memory-page-file-on

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно мониторить озу и своп в режиме реального времени. WMI мне показалось слишком медленно выполняет запросы. WinAPI намного быстрее отдает данные. С озу нет проблем. Все вытягивается через 'GlobalMemoryStatusEx', а вот со свопом там, что-то не то выдает.

Comment: А зачем вы собираетесь мониторить виртуальную память в режиме реального времени? Почему не раз в несколько секунд брать информацию?

Comment: Еще вот такая функция есть https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/zwquerysysteminformation

Comment: Буду смотреть эту функцию. Честно говоря чисто для тренировки решил написать что-то вроде Rainmeter. Все вроде получилось, только со свопом стало интересно. Если ничего не получится с WinAPI, тогда буду через WMI. Спасибо за помощь!